# Kubernetes-JAVA-API Resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I am planning to learn kubernetes and I am looking for good resources (books or any other online tutorials). Basically my end goal is to deploy a JAVA app in kubernetes and manage it through kubernetes API (preferred option would be through kubernetes JAVA client API). In particular my focus is on learning the following aspects - 
1. Kubernetes fundamentals
2. Cluster monitoring
3. App management
4. API based auto-scaling

I searched online and unfortunately couldnt find any JAVA based books or resources (most of them are either GO or just illusstrate cluster management/monitoring through command line). Hence, I am posting this question. Any learning recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to begin with an excelent book
"Kubernetes in action" writen by Marko Luksa

In addition please start with:

- Kubernetes [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/)
- [API Client Libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-client-libraries)
- The Kubernetes Guide For [Java Developers](https://shekhargulati.com/2019/02/02/the-kubernetes-guide-part-1-learn-kubernetes-by-deploying-a-real-world-application-on-it/)
- A [Day in Java Developer’s Life, with a taste of Kubernetes](https://github.com/aws-samples/kubernetes-for-java-developers#a-day-in-java-developers-life-with-a-taste-of-kubernetes)
- [Lynda Resources](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/kubernetes-for-java-developers)
- Building stuff with the [Kubernetes API (Part 2) — Using Java](https://medium.com/programming-kubernetes/building-stuff-with-the-kubernetes-api-part-2-using-java-ceb8a5ff7920)